# CSS animation, play and then reverse animation on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have multiple divs zero width on page load, they are then extended (just after page load) by a keyframe transition like so (for example). Each of these divs has a different final width.

```
@keyframes growN {
    from {width: 0px;}
    to {width: 21vw;}
}
```

I would like to add a second animation that extends the div further (to a fixed value) on hover, and sets it back to its original (post page load animation) width on de-hover (un-hover?). Something like this:

```
@keyframes hover_grow {
    from {width: element.width;}
    to {width: 50vw;}
}
```

Since there are many divs, I'd rather not do the maths myself (separate animation for each div, with its own width in place of element.width).

I have tried the following:

```
bar:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: hover_grow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: grow;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover_grow {
    from {width: initial;}
    to {width: 25vw;}
}

@keyframes hover_grow {
    from {width: initial;}
    to {width: 25vw;}
}
```

This works on hover - the div extends further, but on de-hover, it returns it to its page load, pre animation value (i.e. 0), and its page load animation triggers again. Also, the timing seems to be ignored.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an1o4brL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to work this around is to use a wrapper, animate the initial appearance then grow and shrink the wrapper on hover, the child will follow its parent's width,

other wise use `js`

```css
#bar4 {
  height: 30px;
  transition: width .5s linear;
  display: block;
  animation-name: grow4;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #5e0734;
  margin-top: 0.15vh;
  margin-bottom: 0.15vh;
  margin-left: 0.5vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes grow4 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#bar4Wrap {
  width: 21vw;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}

#bar4Wrap:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar4Wrap">
  <a href="link" id="bar4">Link</a>
</div>
```